# Is this a duplicate website for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, copycat-sites

I was searching for a programming question and found a website that looks quite similar to Stack Overflow though their domain name has an extra word. I'm not sure if this website is part of Stack Overflow.

The URL is: http://www.stackoverflow.dluat.com/

If the above website is not owned by Stack Overflow then what can we do?

Comment: See also: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

Comment: This question about a duplicate website is duplicated. So, double negative makes a positive?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they may be taking Stack Overflow's data, mirroring it and trying to get advertisement revenue off it.

Example:

Real Stack Overflow: [Zoom out button when xy zoom is enbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32215240/zoom-out-button-when-xy-zoom-is-enbled)

Mirrored with Ads: http://www.stackoverflow.dluat.com/questions/32215240/zoom-out-button-when-xy-zoom-is-enbled

Comment: Taking data? You mean posting the questions as is or they have access to SO's database?

Comment: They could be scraping the website manually, or perhaps using the Stack Exchange API: https://api.stackexchange.com/ (I haven't explored it)

Comment: @prudhvi: This is quite common actually, but it should be dealt with. Follow the duplicate chain I linked on the question for more information on how to proceed.